# trying to append a dense layer to vgg19 network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to append a dense layer to vgg19 network, but it gives me the below error. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import tensorflow 
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19 
model = VGG19()  
x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(10,
activation="relu",name="",trainable=True)(model.layers[-1]) 
model = tensorflow.keras.Model(inputs = model.layers[0], outputs = x)
```

> Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 07:39:16) Type "copyright",
>   "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
>
> runfile('/Users/sadegh/Dropbox/Moosavi Khorzooghi-04/test',
>   wdir='/Users/sadegh/Dropbox/Moosavi Khorzooghi-04') 2019-11-29
>   01:51:22.516366: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142]
>   Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not
>   compiled to use: AVX2 FMA 2019-11-29 01:51:22.526913: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service
>   0x7fc84c7a2700 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
>   2019-11-29 01:51:22.526926: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): Host, Default Version Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/sadegh/Dropbox/Moosavi Khorzooghi-04/test', wdir='/Users/sadegh/Dropbox/Moosavi Khorzooghi-04')
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Users/sadegh/Dropbox/Moosavi Khorzooghi-04/test", line 11, in
>   
>       x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu",name="",trainable=True)(model.layers[-1])
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 887, in **call**
>       self._maybe_build(inputs)
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 2122, in _maybe_build
>       self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py",
>   line 163, in assert_input_compatibility
>       if x.shape.ndims is None:
>
> AttributeError: 'Dense' object has no attribute 'shape'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a classification problem, therefore, you should use `softmax` activation instead of `relu` in the output layer. Also you can access input and output of the backbone `VGG19` model. You should manually pool or flatten the output of base model if you instantiate it with default setting. Instead you can set `pooling="avg" or pooling="max"` for global average or max pooling respectively. Moreover, You can use something like following:

```
base_model = VGG19(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', pooling="avg", include_top=False)
x = Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="output")(base_model.output)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
print(model.summary())
```